# 12V voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, 12v

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYi9ef.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: voltage regulator ic]

I have bought the LM78H12K 12V voltage regulator, for the 12V output. My input voltage is 17 V DC, but unfortunately this component is not working as expected.

I have uploaded an image of the module. I read the datasheet but with those instructions I am not able to get 12V output, output is showing me 10V only. What and where I am connecting it wrong?

I was looking for a simple circuit for 12V 5A circuit from a 17V AC 20A transformer.  The 78h12k looked like a simple solution for me as I am not concerned about regulator efficiency.

I am using below circuit for the regulator, but this gives me only 10V output and the regulator does not gets hot.

Please refer to the [datasheet.](https://datasheet4u.com/datasheet-pdf-file/44486/ETC/78H12A/1)

Comment: There is nothing connected to it. It will never work like that.

Comment: @Transistor, I have added a sample circuit, input is 17dc and getting 10v as output. I want 12v.

Comment: Right, a schematic has appeared. What current are you measuring on the output? What is the current rating of the 78H12A? Put the information into your question (not in the comments). Also, check the datasheet for 100 nF capacitors on the input and output. They are usually required to prevent oscillation.

Comment: Does your regulator get **hot**? Did you use a **heatsink**? If it gets hot and you didn't use a heatsink it is trying to protect itself from getting too hot. So it limits the output voltage. Using a **linear** regulator like this is quite **inefficient**. Consider using a **switched regulator module**. Search for LM2596 modules, don't buy the chip, buy a **module** as that will work and getting the chip and all the components around it to work properly is better left to experienced designers.

Comment: This is only an extremely small snippet of the circuit. I don't think Swagatam Innovations is a credible engineering source for refer to if you want circuits to just suddenly work. I think it would be nice if you listed out what your goals are.

Comment: What voltage do you get between IN and GND? What output voltage do you get with no load? What is producing the 17V DC?

Comment: The full-wave bridge is dropping ~1.3 volts, so the effective input is ~15.7 V. Also, check the voltage across the input capacitor t be sure the voltage source to your regulator is not drooping.

Comment: Please delete the silly Paint schematic and add a proper one showing all the components, connections and component values. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I am getting 15.3v 20A DC after rectification from a transformer output. I am looking for steady 12v 5A.

Comment: @Ramesh, you are making it very difficult for anyone to help you. Please show **the full schematic** for your circuit. Find a better datasheet for the device that shows sample circuits including decoupling capacitors. You haven't answered many of the questions in the comments so I suggest you read them all again and see what you have missed. Put all the information into your question.

Comment: @RameshVK what voltage do you get when you disconnect the load? if you have an oscilloscope around, can you connect it to the output so as to check for oscillations? also you say your output is 15.3v 20A, however is that the rated current or is it the actual current you are getting with the circuit working? also if your schematic is right, with a load of 100 ohm you will never ever get 5A out (I = V/R)

Comment: also make sure you didn't get the pins swapped and the case has good contact

Comment: @Transistor, I have used the exact same schematics, not a single more component. this is a old voltage regulator and i couldn't find any schematics for the chip or circuit diagrams for this. Only circuit diagram i derived from the data sheet is given above and I am getting a max of 10v at the output side without any load connected.

Comment: @diegogmx, Transformer is giving actual 20A, but the data sheets does not even says need of any supporting components for this regulator. will you be able to derive a circuit out of data sheet if any supporting components are required please?.

Comment: The 78XX series is very forgiving, but most [datasheets](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l78.pdf) recommend 0.33uF from input to ground and 0.1uF from output to ground.  It is rare, but sometimes if you leave those capacitors out then a 78XX will oscillate and cause the output voltage to be wrong.  Long leads on the input is the most common cause of problems.  Use short leads from rectifier and transformer to the regulator, include the recommended capacitors.

Comment: "*I have used the exact same schematics, not a single more component.*" No, you have a transformer a bridge rectifier and, hopefully, a smoothing capacitor, whose value is critical to the operation of the circuit, none of which are shown on the schematic.